# Meta failed to link my account to Stack Overflow!

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts

I just signed up on Meta (although, I thought I'd signed up before, but I must have been mistaken). After it created my account, it directed me to a generic "something went wrong"-type error page, and it never linked up my account with my Stack Overflow account. :(

Any idea what went wrong or how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/145060?tab=accounts#tab-top?

Comment: I suggest an email to team@stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend switching to Google Profiles if you're having difficulty, for the reasons described below:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/google-offers-named-openids/

Comment: I'm trying to link this account to my OpenID (Google) account, but it's not working for some reason. I click the "Log In" button when presented with my OpenID URL, but it just takes me back to this account. :(

Comment: @brian as I said in the above link, I highly recommend getting a Google Profile. Looks like your IP addresses are changing between HTTP requests which means we can't securely map your GMail OpenID between sites.

Comment: I see now. The profiles thing seems to have worked. I still lost my questions/answers on SF and SU however. Oh well.